# How do these statements work?

Tags: mysql, select

There are 2 tables x and y.

How do these statements work?

```
WHERE x.continent = y.continent
  AND x.name != y.name
```

Comment: Can you give more detail on what is your problem/question.Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a SQL query, the where clause defines the conditions on what is selected.
In your statement, the continent column from the x table and continent column from the y table must be the same.

The second statement is a condition that the rows must have different names, but I don't believe the syntax is correct as 'NOT EQUALS' is the following symbol for SQL: '<>'

Comment: != is also not equals in SQL.

Comment: Hmm, learned something new. Was told that != doesn't work and you had to use '<>'. Thanks